# Ranking numerical values by row in data frame in R base

Tags: r, dataframe, rank

I'm trying to rank continuous values by row in a data frame. For example, from this data frame

```
df0 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(5, 0.1, 1), 
                 x2 = rnorm(5, 0.0, 1),
                 x3 = rnorm(5, 0.3, 1),
                 x4 = rnorm(5, 0.2, 1))
df0
          x1          x2          x3         x4
1  2.1540546 -0.95349328  0.06747390  1.4737404
2  0.1284843 -1.41162850  0.02273785 -0.9432357
3 -0.5162803  0.03551863  0.09552951 -0.1144275
4 -0.5455716  0.19596625 -0.71353323  0.3566051
5  0.6864848  0.22596630  0.91770037 -0.4423302
```

I'd like to obtain this ranking (taking the lowest value as 1, the second lowest as 2, and so forth):

```
df1_ranked
  x1_ranked x2_ranked x3_ranked x4_ranked x5_ranked
1         4         4         1         2         3
2         1         1         3         3         2
3         2         3         4         1         4
4         3         2         2         4         1
```

I can't think of any easy solution to this task. Ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Rank per row over multiple columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227828/rank-per-row-over-multiple-columns-in-r) or [Ranking rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530731/ranking-rows-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to use `apply` to loop over the rows (`MARGIN = 1`) and use `rank`

```
t(apply(df0, 1, rank))
```

---

Or use `rowRanks` from `matrixStats` after converting to `matrix`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowRanks(as.matrix(df0))
```